# Python: How to create a composed list?

Tags: python, list

I'm quite new in Python. I suppose my question is simple, but I don't find any answer. I would like to create, delete a composed list (as a C struct) and access items inside:

```
    for i in list1
      create item in list2[list3[StringVar1, StringVar2], bool1, Frame1]
      item.list3[StringVar1] = i
      item.list3[StringVar2] = value
      item.bool1 = True
      item.Frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
```

How can I write that in Python?

*Edit: Martijn Pieters is right, I've just corrected.*

Comment: This is not valid Python.

Comment: @Tichodroma hence the question "How can I write that in Python?"

Comment: The closest thing to a C-Struct that I can think of is `namedtuple` if you guys have a better interpretation, then please comment, so that I can change my answer.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: That'd have been my answer, but you posted it already.

Comment: Looks to me like you meant to write `item.bool1 = True`, and `item.Frame1 = tk.Frame(self)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Whoah, I beat you to something. Its an honor Mr. Pieters. I really do look up to you :) _jumps with joy_

Answer (score 4):

I don't exactly understand by what you mean when you say *composed list*, but indeed you can have a struct in Python.

Ideally, you mean that you want an immutable C-Struct like object then, you can create it quite easily. In Python its called a `namedtuple`, or atleast this is the closest that I have come across. You can of course create your own generic object in Python, and add arguments, but that would be a dynamic struct instead.

Ideally, in C, you would have a struct like this ->

```
struct tag_name
{
   type attribute;
   type attribute2;
   /* ... */
};
```

And you could access the attributes of the `struct` like so `tag_name.attribute`. So, this is how a `namedtuple` works:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> NetworkAddress = namedtuple('NetworkAddress',['hostname','port'])
>>> a = NetworkAddress('www.python.org',80)
>>> a.hostname
'www.python.org'
>>> a.port
80
>>> host, port = a
>>> len(a)
2
>>> type(a)
<class '_ _main_ _.NetworkAddress'>
>>> isinstance(a, tuple)
True
>>>
```

If there is anything that you would like in specific, then please update your question to explain *composed list* so that I can update this answer.

However, this is typical of a statically typed language like C, since we're using Python, we can use some cool dynamic properties, so you an essentially create an object that you can add properties to as you see fit:

```
class DynamicObject(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

---

## Console session

```
>>> class DynamicObject(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
>>> happy_obj = DynamicObject(name="Happy Gilmore")
>>> happy_obj.name
'Happy Gilmore'
```

*Credits* ->

https://stackoverflow.com/users/320726/6502 for the dynamic object code. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a Python dictionary

```
item = {}
item["list2"] = {}
item["list2"]["list3"] = {}
item["list2"]["list3"][Var1] = Value1
item["list2"]["list3"][Var2] = Value2
...
```

You can assign another dictionary or a list as a value as well.

As far as delete is concerned you can use the "del" keyword to delete. For ex

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary["name"] = {}
dictionary["name1"] = {}
del dictionary["name1"]
dictionary
{'name': {}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know that new style objects (anything derived from `object`) have a `__dict__` member, which is a `dict`. So you can do:

```
class X(object):
    pass

x = X()
x.__dict__["a"] = 1
x.a #1
```

another way to do this is to user `setattr` and `getattr`:

```
setattr(x, "b", 2) # same as x.__dict__["b"] = 2
```

You can use this to build named access to some input structure, however you will need names and values in your compound input structure (essentially, something like nested dicts for all nodes that are to have named children)

Answer (score 0):

However, I think your data struct is wrong. For the use method is like array like in c. That means we can find elem by the number index, so you can't use list like `list3[StringVar1,StringVar2]`.
Maybe the dictionary in python can meet your need. If you want to use `item.list3` you must define a class in python.

Comment: I described the data structure, not the wat to access it: there are 2 items in list3.